# Are there environment variables which are reliable always set?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

Are there environment variables which are reliable always set?

Comment: Can you give an example of why you're asking this question?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bash, the following variables are read-only and should always be available in the shell:

```
BASH_VERSINFO
EUID
SHELLOPTS
SHLVL
UID
```

They will even be set in Bash scripts that are run by:

```
env - scriptname
```

since Bash sets them when it starts the script, not from the parent environment.

This variable is read-only, but it's not set by default. You can set it by performing a regex match.

```
BASH_REMATCH
```

If you want it to equal "foo", just do:

```
[[ foo =~ .* ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

No. One can start a program with an empty environment:

```
env - your_application
```